# Apache-Kafka node is getting down frequently

Tags: apache-kafka

We are having a setup of 3 zookeepers and 3 kafka in our requirement. Recently , we faced issue like one of the kafka services is shutting down automatically . When we checked in depth , the same is getting down frequently every month on the same date and there are no scripts or cronjobs enabled in the server. Also there are no trace of logs why it is getting shutdown . Could you please let us know why it is getting down frequently.

The only logs we can see other than shutting down has been attached here.

[image]

Comment: Hi Keerthi. To make this question easier to answer and google, please provide more info, logs, configuration files... :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Last I checked, broker ID should be positive. Notice it's always removing 0

Comment: Maybe you can check your `/var/log/messages` for "killed process XXX"?

Comment: Hello , We could not find any kill process in /var/log/messages and also there is no issue with Kafka server with broker ID 0 . Among three Kafka brokers , Kafka server with broker ID 2 is getting down automatically. I have attached full logs.

Comment: We have observed some issues in zookeeper . attaching the logs here :
ERROR Unexpected exception causing shutdown while sock still open (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerHandler)

Answer (score 0):

Please find logs here 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKnTo.png)